# Опробован-апробирован

Tags: орфография, однокоренные-слова

Интересно, а почему в слове "опробовал" приставка "о-", а в слове "апробирован" (фактически одно и то же) - "а-"? Чем отличаются эти слова?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глаголы "опробовать и апробировать" различаются по смыслу, а также этимологией,хотя оба они восходят к латинскому глаголу probare – испытывать, пробовать.

Можно услышать такую рекомендацию: "Нельзя путать слова апробировать (лат. approbare), что означает "дать официальное одобрение на основании испытания, проверки", и опробовать (родственное слово проба) — "подвергнуть испытанию до применения".

ОПРОБОВАТЬ - Подвергнуть - подвергать испытанию, прежде чем начать использование, применение. О. новое оборудование. О. вакцину на животных. О. методы восточной медицины.

АПРОБИРОВАТЬ (лат. approbare)  – это официально одобрить (после проверки), а также утвердить. Словообразование: апробация - апробировать,суффикс ИРОВА, ср.: классификация - классифицировать): А. научное открытие. Самолёты новой марки уже апробированы. На  этот проект еще аппробации не получили.

С точки зрения орфографии, слова различаются приставками А и О. Вариант А - это латинская приставка AP, а вариант О - русская приставка О (пробовать - опробовать) со значением направить действие во все стороны, сравнить: осмотреть, ощупать. Слово "проба" известно в языке с 17 – начала 18 века (от нем. Probe).

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, "апробировать" имеет значение "одобрить", то есть это разные слова.

Answer (score 1):

К вышесказанному уместно добавить, что слово "probieren" есть и в современном немецком языке (пытаться, пробовать, что-либо сделать). Более того, в этом же языке есть и "approbieren" (допускать к практике, одобрять ). Прижилось это слово с аналогичным значением и в испанском -  "aprobar", и в итальянском - "approvare' . Думаю, то именно по этой причине мы его воспринимаем  как синоним к русскому слову "опробовать", хотя в толковых словарях ему придают немного другое значение.  И конечно же, отсюда приставка" а" в  этом слове: нет приставки "о" в иностранных языках. Думаю, что "о" -  исконно русская приставка.